# Problem with hooking ntdll.dll calls

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system, system-calls

I'm currently working on hooking ntdll.dll calls via dll injection.
At first, I create thread in existing process via `CreateRemoteThread()` then I load my dll via `LoadLibrary` and finally hook calls on `PROCESS_ATTACH`.

Injection works fine, but then I want to log all registry and file system queries. And the problem is that it doesn't work properly.

I decided to publish code via PasteBin, because piece is pretty big. Here is the link: 
http://pastebin.com/39r4Me6B

I'm trying to hook `ZwOpenKey`, then log key content and then launch "true" function by pointer. Function `NOpenKey` gets executed, but process stops without any errors.

Does anyone see any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use OllyDbg, `ZwOpenKey` starts with 5 bytes `MOV EAX, 77`.

You can overwrite these bytes like so `JMP _myZwOpenKey` then from there you can do whatever with the values on the stack, restore all registers then do a `JMP 7C90D5B5` which is address of `ZwOpenKey` + 5 bytes.

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                 Comments
7C90D5AF      90            NOP
7C90D5B0  /$  B8 77000000   MOV EAX,77              ; ntdll.ZwOpenKey(guessed rg1,Arg2,Arg3)
7C90D5B5  |.  BA 0003FE7F   MOV EDX,7FFE0300
7C90D5BA  |.  FF12          CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EDX]
7C90D5BC  \.  C2 0C00       RETN 0C
```

I usually do these in Assembly that way I don't have to mess around a lot with type casting and all that. Hope this helps.